# NIntegration and DSolve with same variable

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, list-manipulation

I need to solve this problem:

[image]

Then follows the code, with:

```
V[z] = 0.28125` (-5.` + Cosh[3.` z]) Sech[1.5` z]^2;
K[z] = (0.42187680654931936` Sech[1.5` z]^0.454929658551372`);
```

I try to perform the DSolve as "s1" and the integrations as "dataI"

```
s1 = List[
       ParallelTable[
        NDSolve[{-y''[z] + (V[z] - m^2) y[z] == 0, 
          y[0] == 0.690988298942671` , y'[0] == 0}, y, {z, -30, 30}], {m, 
         0.75, 10, .1}]];
     dataI = Flatten[ParallelTable[NIntegrate[
 (NIntegrate[(K[z]*(y[z] /. s1)), {z, -30, 30}, 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
      "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}])^2*Exp[-m x], {m, 0.75, 10},
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], {x,
  0.01, 5, 0.01}]]]
```

But the result is not correct. I need a way to run the parameter m in a single loop to solve both integrals as ODE to compute C(x).

Comment: With the specified boundary conditions, the only solution of the ODE is zero, independent of `m`.